# Javascript/Jquery validating decimal input on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to find a way to validate a text input on key press, I want to allow numbers only inside my text input including decimals.
I was taking the approach of using jQuery.keydown, and checking what the key was and using.

**input numbers max length 999.999**

-

my result after **.**  (point) 3 number it is goog. but 99999.999

I need 999.999,222.222,22.01 ->
**max length +++.+++**

*this my code*

```
<input type="text" id="spinEdit2" class="aSpinEdit" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var txt = document.getElementById('spinEdit2');
    txt.addEventListener('keyup', myFunc);

    function myFunc(e) {
        var val = this.value;

        var re1 = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9])/g;
            val = re1.exec(val);
            //console.log(val);
            if (val) {
                this.value = val[0];
            } else {
                this.value = "";
            }

    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
/^([0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{0,3})?)/g
```

In case you want the details: the `{1,3}` means the preceding thing can happen from 1 to 3 times. The `(?:)` is a non-captured group -- it's a grouping of the following symbols, but it doesn't capture to any variables like $1.